# How can I use the following cmd for multiple files?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

The following function allows me to list detailed data for a single file, what can I have to do to get it to run, if there are multiple files in a variable.

```
function Text ($file) {
    try {
        $content = Get-Content $ASCIIfile
        $text = $content | out-string
        $result = [regex]::matches($text, '\b\S+\b') 
        $statistik = $result | Select-Object -Expand Captures | Group-Object Value -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
        $numbers = @{
            'Anzahl Wörter'              = $result.Count
            'Anzahl Zeilen'              = $content.Count
            'Zeichen (mit Leerzeichen)'  = ($text.Length - 2)
            'Zeichen (ohne Leerzeichen)' = ($text -replace '\s', '').Length
        }
        $('=' * 20)
        $($numbers | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-string)
    }
    catch {
        write-host "Falsche Eingabe"
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare `$file` in the parameter list, then read from an undefined variable `$ASCIIfile` inside the function. Typo?

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the input to `ForEach-Object`, and replace the previous variable reference to `$file` with `$_` (`$_` refers to the current input item received by `ForEach-Object`):

```
function Text ($file) {
    $file | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $content = Get-Content $_
            $text = $content | out-string
            $result = [regex]::matches($text, '\b\S+\b') 
            $statistik = $result | Select-Object -Expand Captures | Group-Object Value -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
            $numbers = @{
                'Anzahl Wörter'              = $result.Count
                'Anzahl Zeilen'              = $content.Count
                'Zeichen (mit Leerzeichen)'  = ($text.Length - 2)
                'Zeichen (ohne Leerzeichen)' = ($text -replace '\s', '').Length
            }
            $('=' * 20)
            $($numbers | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-string)
        }
        catch {
            write-host "Falsche Eingabe"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you every much, but this doesn't work, if I select a whole folder of txt files, it says permission denied, even if I use administrator and set-executionspolicy unrestricted

Comment: @kaiwenShao How are you executing the function? `Text path\to\folder\*.txt` should work just fine

Comment: yeah ofc, but what I want is to be able to use it in a whole folder